# If all energy is removed from an object, what will it stop moving relative to?

Tags: energy, reference-frames, relativity

If you somehow removed all energy from an object, what would it stop moving relative to?

According to relativity, an object's position is not relative to the universe, just reference points, and, as I can understand it, reference points are just a way to comprehend relativity and are not properties of matter. If an object has no way to move, does the entire universe move around it? Is it just plain impossible to suck all energy out of an object (even with full control of the universe or something extreme like that)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Quantum-mechanicaly and relativisticaly the energy of a given object **is never removed completely** (Heisenberg uncertainty relations, relativistisc rest mass)
2. Assuming we talk about kinetic energy, kinetic energy is defined with respect to **a specific reference frame**. This reference frame can be related to another object or not. The kinetic energy can be *transfered to* or *absorbed by* another object (for example in a collision), then the 1st object (assuming all kinetic energy is transfered) stops moving with respect to the reference frame mentioned before. **Note** that this whole system (of collision) can itself be part of another reference frame which itself moves.

So whether a given object moves or not is defined with respect to specific [reference frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference), in some it may be moving; in others not.